# Delete first item in each key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm kind of stumped here and would love some help.

So I have a dictionary like so

```
{'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}
```

and I need to create a function which will automatically delete the first item in each list/key, so it should become

```
{'a':[2, 3], 'b':[5, 6]}
```

I know I should use the pop function, but it kind of gets confusing when there's way more than 2 keys and 3 values

Comment: Well before I tried some random stuff that didn't work. But I just thought of doing it like this, but I'm not sure if it'll work since I just thought of it and haven't tried it yet

    def delRow(self):
        for key in self._table:
            self._table[key].pop()


oh sorry, I'm not too sure how formatting works here, how can I make that look better?

Comment: you shouldnt ask questions you havent tried and tested yourself. You couldve come to the answer yourself if you took just 5 minutes to think about it and do some research.

Comment: `d = {k: d[k][1:] for k in d}` (assuming `d` is a dict object)

Comment: Aha, so sorry, what I had going right now just worked. I just had to approach it differently and as I was typing the question I got the idea.

Answer (score 6):

You can use dictionary-comprehension for that:

```
>>> a = {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}
>>> {k: a[k][1:] for k in a}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': [5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with a one-liner using the `map` built-in function combined with a lambda function. Another advantage of this approach is that there's no copying involved (like in the slicing solution):

```
doc = {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}
map(lambda v: v.pop(0), doc.values())
```

This applies `list.pop(0)` on each value of your dict.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution,

```
    dict1={'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}

    for item in dict1.values():
        item.remove(item[0])
```

The for-loop moves through the values in the dictionary represented by 'dict1.values()'. The values are a set of lists, the '.remove()' function of the list removes the first occurrence of the element given, so if you give it the first element found in the list it would likewise remove it.

Hope this was useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the values of the dictionary and pop them one at a time. If you need further functionality or control, you can place it in a function.

```
dict_ = {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}

for val in dict_.values()
    val.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the dict & splice the list.

```
var1 = {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}

for element in var1:
    var1[element] = var1[element][1:]
```